# Can't import project into repository svn

Tags: svn, debian

sorry my english, I from Italy.
Through ssh I have install on my "ReadyNas Duo" the server subversion with apt-get, without error. I create the repository `svnadmin create /MyDeveloper/svn/repos`, I have checked and the folder of svn there are.

After create I have import the my project Java into repository `svn import MyProj file:///MyDeveloper/svn/repos/MyProj -m "Prima importazione del progetto"`, but it return an error `Can't set position pointer in file /MyDeveloper/svn/repos/db/revs/0: Invalid argument`. Same error with `svn list` and other command. I have checked the permission, but are set.

I ask a lot of help, because otherwise I can not work on my projects

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to import to the repository you created, not a subfolder:

```
$ svn import . file:///MyDeveloper/svn/repos -m "prima importazione del progetto"
```

Apologies for my crap Italian.

Comment: Certainly much better than my crap English

Comment: In either case, I hope you (a) find it helpful and (b)accept the answer.

Comment: Same problem. I'm going crazy for this problem
I have test with subversive eclipse, same error.

Comment: I not installed the libapache-svn, because i work in the my local network, I do not use the connection http but ssh. Could affect this?

Comment: What I did everything from the command line, then I wanted to try with eclipse, but error is equals

Comment: @Carmine use the exact command I've put above, no ssh or http.

Comment: Yes I connect on my nas with ssh, then use the your command, but is equal

Answer (score 0):

- Try to do a check out of your (empty) repository
- copy your project
- into your new created working copy  commit changes.

I never do the svn import command but do always a checkout. I need it anyway to continue to work!